# Usar 2 fonts numa frase

Tags: html, css-font-face, font

Eu tenho um site que o cliente pediu que eu usasse um tipo de fonte para umas coisas e outro tipo para outras.
E pediu que o mail fosse todo com um tipo de letra(tipo1) mas esse tipo não tem @ portanto pediu que o mail fosse todo com o tipo1 mas o @ com tipo2 (um bocado estúpido na minha opinião mas quem sou eu).

Eu tentei por o @ dentro de uma  mas aparece em baixo e nem sequer aparece com esse tipo2. Aqui vou deixar o exemplo de como o código está:

```
<p class="footer_txt"><a href="mailto:geral@saberinfinito.pt" style="font-family: edosz;"><img src="images/mail.png">&nbsp;geral<div style="font-family:finger;">@</div>saberinfinito.pt</a></p>
```

Caso seja útil para responder, o tipo de letra (tipo1) é edosz.tff e o tipo de letra (tipo2) é FingerPaint-Regular.ttf.
E também deixo aqui o css de ambos os tipos:

```
    @font-face{
    font-family: "edosz";
    src: url('edosz.ttf');
}

@font-face{
    font-family: "finger";
    src: url('FingerPaint-Regular.ttf');
}
```

Comment: Olá, o ideal é criar uma regra que já identificaria o "@" e altere automaticamente ou seria aceitável adicionar <span> ?

Answer (score 4):

Tente assim:

```
.tipo1 {
    font-family: edosz;
}

.tipo2 {
    font-family: finger;
}

<span class="tipo1">Texto 1</span><span class="tipo2">Texto 2</span>
```

Comment: O exemplo acima ta legal mas use class ao invés de id, outra dica e usar o google web font

Comment: @joaomarcelo Opa irei editar para class